# None-missing rows were removed in geom_point in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why the rows in this data was claimed to be missing and removed in the plot even though the x-scale isn't out of range? I have tried to include xlim without success. What do I miss here? This is the figure [image] Gp2 (geom_point) isn't included in the plot. The code I used is as follows:

```
        df1 <- data.frame(x=c(2,4:8),
                          y=c(1.030928,4.123711,3.092784,8.247423,9.278351,4.123711))
        df2 <- data.frame(x=3:8,
                          y=c(1.700680,1.360544,4.081633,3.401361,3.061224,9.183673))

         require(ggplot2)

         ggplot(NULL, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
            geom_bar(data = df1, aes(fill="Gp1", shape="Gp1"),
                     stat= "identity") +
            geom_point(data = df2, stat= "identity", size = 5,
                       aes(shape="Gp2", fill="Gp2")) +
            ylab("%") + xlab("grades") +
            ggtitle("Test figure") +
            scale_shape_manual(values = c(23, NA)) +
            scale_fill_manual(values = c("#6699CC","#000099")) +
            guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE),
                   shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape=0), reverse = TRUE))
```

This gives warning message:
Removed 6 rows containing missing values (geom_point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your code piece-by-piece we can easily find that `scale_shape_manual` is the culprit here, everything before that works find. (If you had made a *minimal* example, you would have easily found that..)

You have told `ggplot` that all the shapes for `geom_point` should be `Gp2`, which is the second shape you have mapped. So it will look at the second entry in `values` and find there is an `NA`. So you yourself told `ggplot` that it should give `NA` shapes to all points.

(Note that you mapped shape `Gp1` in `geom_bar`, but `geom_bar` doesn't take that aesthetic..)